# how to access the putty to ubuntu server

Tags: ssh, putty

I am new to Ubuntu, I have it installed on my computer and I am trying to connect to my Ubuntu machine remotely through PuTTY. I am getting the IP address of the Ubuntu machine using ifconfig. I'm trying to connect to this IP address with PuTTY but I am getting the following error message:

connection failed.

Comment: Can you `ping <server IP address>` (IP address of your Ubuntu server) from the client where PuTTY should be used? Can you `telnet <server IP address> 22` from the client?

Comment: Did you install an SSH server (`openssh-server`) on the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Yes i do this in both the PC's .But when we open the putty in windows and give the IP address of Ubuntu then it shows this error "network time out". But they are in LAN then why this problem?                                                                                                            And SSH  server(openssh-server) is installed already.

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting to your ubuntu machine using putty ? Can you please share the steps or command if its via cmd.

Anyways putty uses .ppk key. So make sure you have your pem converted to ppk and also no security/network blockage on machine access.

To login using cmd :

```
C:\Users\dmittal\Downloads\Keys>putty.exe user@hostip -i key
eg:
C:\Users\dmittal\Downloads\Keys>putty.exe dmittal@51.62.157.133 -i syd.ppk
```

By option -i we need to pass the path of key.

Comment: I install the putty on to the window and i try to run the program from window but that program is actually run on the ubuntu server then what i do?

Comment: You need to access ubuntu server from your windows machine?

Comment: what is the procedure to access the putty in ubuntu server?

Comment: For accessing an ubuntu server from ubuntu putty is not required. putty or any terminal is used while accessing ubuntu machine from windows. What you can do is open command prompt.(Run cmd). Then locate your putty.exe on windows machine. Move to that directory from command prompt and run the above command.

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating things here. PuTTY only uses .ppk keys if you have configured it to do so - by default, it uses regular password authentication (which is also the default for `openssh-server`). Also there's no need to use the command line from the windows side.

Comment: Yes. It depends on the server's authentication mechanism whether its key or pwd. I assumed key and explained that. Instead of command line would be do directly by opening a simple session.